# Indenting multi-lines doesn't work in Emacs

Tags: emacs, indentation

I edit `.ml` in `Emacs`. `tab` key indents well one line. But when I select a block of lines, `tab` key doesn't indent anything... Here is my [.emacs](http://pastebin.com/dW3WzBYb), could anyone tell me what is wrong?

Also, `tab` doesn't indent comments at all, no matter whether it is 1 line or several lines... is it normal?

Comment: Do you get the same behavior when you start Emacs as `emacs -q`?

Comment: If I start Emacs with `-q`, the indenting of multi-lines works well. But the other visual effects (color, size) are lost...

Comment: You could comment out portions of your .emacs to try to isolate the problematic lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `M-x indent-region RET`.

The `TAB` key only indents the current line regardless if the region is active or not (but it would be a neat idea to implement a package to change the behavior).

When it comes to comments, it is up to the major mode. I don't know `ml-mode`, but major modes typically do indent comments.

Comment: Many (most?) programming language modes, including `lisp-mode`, `python-mode`, `ruby-mode` and any based off of `cc-mode`, will indent the whole region if the region is active.

Comment: @ataylor, whatdoyouknow, you'll learn something new every day -- thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Complain to the author of your major mode: the default TAB binding is designed to tweakable by major-modes, but many major modes just override it locally instead and then often fail to reproduce the default behavior faithfully.